# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy and CORS not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this policy here that is supposed to only allow access from my web application. However, if I enter the url of the object on S3, I can still access it.

What else do I need to set to make sure that the items in my bucket can only be accessed from my web application.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy15721415129441",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt15721415129441",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:Referer": "https://localhost:55723/*"
        }
      },
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::ACC_NO:root"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

CORS Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://localhost:55723</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Is your web application on AWS or where?

Comment: It’s on my own web host.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an AWS S3 policy that denies all IPs except than the one you specify, example -

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",

  "Statement": [

    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"}

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample CORS config -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**References -**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html